# Is the converse of Liouville's theorem (complex analysis)true?

Tags: complex-analysis

If it is true,please give an intuitive as well as mathematical proof for that.
If it is not true,please give intuitive idea and an example to disprove it.

Comment: LT states that every bounded analytic function is a constant.  And yes, every constant is a bounded analytic function.

Comment: Do you really mean to ask if every constant function is a bounded analytic function? That doesn't seem to be a sane question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if a constant is an analytic function? Yes, constants are analytic.